# Optimise grouping 512x512 coordinates into 117 smaller, quartered chunks

Tags: kotlin, leaflet

I'm creating image map tiles for Leaflet.js based on data from a computer game. I'm processing the map data in Kotlin. A map tile server for Leaflet.js has to host image tiles at [various zoom-levels](https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/), so I need to create them.

These are the resolutions I want to create, based on a source image of 512x512px.

- 512x512 pixels (zoomed out the most)
- 256x256 pixels
- 128x128 pixels
- 64x64 pixels
- 32x32 pixels (the most zoomed in)

A code example is at the bottom of this post.

I'm using `groupBy` at the moment, but the performance isn't great.

```kotlin
// for each possible chunk size...
ChunkSize.entries.flatMap { chunkSize ->
  // and for each tile...
  chunk.tiles.entries.groupBy(
    // get the chunk the tile belongs to
    { (tile, _) -> tile.toChunkPosition(chunkSize) }
  ) { (tile, colour) ->
    tile to colour
  }.map { (chunkPosition, tiles) ->
    // aggregate the grouped tiles into a map, 
    // and create a new chunk
    Chunk(
      tiles = tiles.toMap(),
      size = chunkSize,
      position = chunkPosition,
    )
  }
}
// this can take up to 0.5 seconds
```

It takes around 0.5 seconds to convert a 512x512px source image into

- 1 512x512px tile
- 4 256x256px tiles
- 16 128x128px tiles
- 32 64x64px tiles
- 64 32x32px tiles

I'd like to improve the performance.

#### Options

##### Sorting and chunking/windowing

Using [windows](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/windowed.html) won't be easy, because the data in the tiles isn't necessarily continuous. There might be gaps between some tiles.

##### Grouping

I've tried using [`Grouping`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-grouping/index.html), but I didn't note a significant difference. The lazy evaluation isn't useful here, and using a mutable map to try and improve the accumulation didn't help either.

```kotlin
ChunkSize.entries.flatMap { chunkSize ->
  val grouped: Map<ChunkPosition, MutableMap<TilePosition, Colour>> =
    chunk.tiles.entries.groupingBy { (tile, _) ->
      tile.toChunkPosition(chunkSize)
    }.fold(
      initialValueSelector = { _, _ -> mutableMapOf() },
    ) { _, accumulator, (tilePosition, colour) ->
      accumulator[tilePosition] = colour
      accumulator
    }

  grouped.entries.map { (chunkPosition, tiles) ->
    Chunk(
      tiles = tiles,
      size = chunkSize,
      position = chunkPosition,
    )
  }
}
```

##### Optimise `toChunkPosition`?

The function for getting the chunk position for every tile, and it's using division, which can be slow.

```kotlin
fun TilePosition.toChunkPosition(chunkSize: ChunkSize) =
  ChunkPosition(
    floor(x.toDouble() / chunkSize.lengthInTiles.toDouble()).toInt(),
    floor(y.toDouble() / chunkSize.lengthInTiles.toDouble()).toInt(),
  )
```

##### Coroutines

I'm open to using coroutines, so work can be done in parallel, but first I want to optimise the existing code.

#### Full code

This is a simplified example. The chunk sizes have been reduced to 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16 pixels.

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.floor
import kotlin.math.pow
import kotlin.math.roundToInt
import kotlin.time.measureTimedValue

val sourceChunk = Chunk(
  size = ChunkSize.MAX,
  position = ChunkPosition(0, 0),
  // create some dummy test data
  tiles = listOf(
    "0000000000000088",
    "1111111110000088",
    "0000000000000088",
    "0000000222722288",
    "0090000000700000",
    "3393333330700000",
    "0090000000700000",
    "0090000444744444",
    "0090000000700000",
    "5595555000700000",
    "0090000000000000",
    "0090000066666666",
  ).flatMapIndexed { y, row ->
    row.mapIndexed { x, colour ->
      TilePosition(x, y) to Colour("$colour")
    }
  }.toMap()
)

fun main() {
  println("Source chunk")
  printChunk(sourceChunk)
  println("-------")

  val (chunks, time) = measureTimedValue {
    subdivideChunk(sourceChunk)
  }

  chunks.forEach {
    println("-------")
    printChunk(it)
  }
  println("-------")
  println("took: $time")
}

fun subdivideChunk(chunk: Chunk): List<Chunk> {


  return ChunkSize.entries.flatMap { chunkSize ->

  val grouped: Map<ChunkPosition, MutableMap<TilePosition, Colour>> =
    chunk.tiles.entries.groupingBy { (tile, _) ->
      tile.toChunkPosition(chunkSize)
    }.fold(
      initialValueSelector = { _, _ -> mutableMapOf() },
    ) { _, accumulator, (tilePosition, colour) ->
      accumulator[tilePosition] = colour
      accumulator
    }

  grouped.entries.map { (chunkPosition, tiles) ->
    Chunk(
      tiles = tiles,
      size = chunkSize,
      position = chunkPosition,
    )
  }

    chunk.tiles.entries.groupBy(
      { (tile, _) -> tile.toChunkPosition(chunkSize) }
    ) { (tile, colour) ->
      tile to colour
    }.map { (chunkPosition, tiles) ->
      Chunk(
        tiles = tiles.toMap(),
        size = chunkSize,
        position = chunkPosition,
      )
    }

    chunk.tiles.entries
      .groupingBy { (tile, _) ->
        tile.toChunkPosition(chunkSize)
      }.fold(mutableMapOf<TilePosition, Colour>()) { accumulator, (tilePosition, colour) ->
        accumulator += tilePosition to colour
        accumulator
      }.map { (chunkPosition, tiles) ->
        Chunk(
          tiles = tiles,
          size = chunkSize,
          position = chunkPosition,
        )
      }
  }
}

fun printChunk(chunk: Chunk) {
  println("chunk ${chunk.position} ${chunk.size}")
  val minX = chunk.tiles.keys.minOf { it.x }
  val minY = chunk.tiles.keys.minOf { it.y }
  val maxX = chunk.tiles.keys.maxOf { it.x }
  val maxY = chunk.tiles.keys.maxOf { it.y }

  (minY..maxY).forEach { y ->
    (minX..maxX).forEach { x ->
      print(chunk.tiles[TilePosition(x, y)]?.rgba ?: " ")
    }
    println()
  }
}


data class Chunk(
  val tiles: Map<TilePosition, Colour>,
  val size: ChunkSize,
  val position: ChunkPosition,
) {
  val topLeftTile: TilePosition = position.toTilePosition(size)
  val bottomRightTile: TilePosition = TilePosition(
    x = topLeftTile.x + size.lengthInTiles - 1,
    y = topLeftTile.y + size.lengthInTiles - 1,
  )

  val xTileRange = topLeftTile.x..bottomRightTile.x
  val yTileRange = topLeftTile.y..bottomRightTile.y

  operator fun contains(tilePosition: TilePosition): Boolean =
    tilePosition.x in xTileRange && tilePosition.y in yTileRange
}

data class Colour(val rgba: String)

data class TilePosition(val x: Int, val y: Int)

fun TilePosition.toChunkPosition(chunkSize: ChunkSize) =
  ChunkPosition(
    floor(x.toDouble() / chunkSize.lengthInTiles.toDouble()).toInt(),
    floor(y.toDouble() / chunkSize.lengthInTiles.toDouble()).toInt(),
  )


data class ChunkPosition(val x: Int, val y: Int)

fun ChunkPosition.toTilePosition(chunkSize: ChunkSize) =
  TilePosition(
    x * chunkSize.lengthInTiles,
    y * chunkSize.lengthInTiles,
  )


enum class ChunkSize(
  val zoomLevel: Int,
) : Comparable<ChunkSize> {
  CHUNK_512(-1),
  CHUNK_256(0),
  CHUNK_128(1),
  CHUNK_064(2),
  CHUNK_032(3),
  ;

  /** 1, 2, 4, 8, or 16 */
  val lengthInTiles: Int = 2f.pow(3 - zoomLevel).roundToInt()

  companion object {
    val entries: Set<ChunkSize> = values().toSet()

    val MAX: ChunkSize = entries.maxByOrNull { it.lengthInTiles }!!
    val MIN: ChunkSize = entries.minByOrNull { it.lengthInTiles }!!
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not near a computer right now to look into this deeper, but why do you store a 2D array as a flat hashmap of 2d position -> value? It sounds like a very inefficient way to store just a matrix.

Comment: @broot what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that my understanding is that you work on 2d arrays of tiles, but for some reason you decided to use hashmaps instead of arrays. I expect `map[TilePosition(2, 3)]` to be much slower than `arr[2][3]`. But I don't say this has to be a bottleneck. Another thing, why in `toChunkPosition()` you convert to double, then divide, floor and convert back to int? Isn't it the same as simply `x / chunkSize.lengthInTiles`? It should be much faster.

Comment: Also, I don't really understand your concept of zoom levels and tiles. In a real map application when we zoom out we decrease the quality, we decrease resolution, so it makes sense to have separate tiles for different zoom levels. If I understood you correctly, you don't plan to decrease the resolution and when we zoom out to a maximum, we basically download all existing data. So what is the point to download separate tiles with exactly the same data after zooming in?

Comment: `floor(...)` rounds down towards negative infinity, `x / chunkSize.lengthInTiles` rounds down to zero. `Tile(-33, 0)` should be in `Chunk(-2,0, size=CHUNK_032)`.

Comment: The tile server needs to host tiles at various zoom levels. Each tile must have the same uniform resolution, e.g. 256x256px. In order to create those tiles, I need to divide the source image into smaller segments, which I later scale to be 256x256px. So when the zoom level increases by 1, the resolution will double, but the image is split up into 4 sub-tiles to improve performance in the web browser. You can read more here: https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/

Comment: Actually, the part about image processing is also quite confusing to me, because there is no image processing in your code sample. Do you mean real images like PNG or just "maps of data"? If they are real images then do you use above Kotlin code to process each pixel of the image separately, as `Colour` class? This would be really bad for the performance. Images should be processed with image processing libraries, they could be tens times faster than our per-pixel algorithm in Kotlin/Java.

Comment: The source data comes from a game, so it's not image data. It's received as a size-optimised JSON object that maps x/y coordinates to a 'prototype ID', and another JSON object that maps 'prototype ID' to a colour. I convert and group the tiles into a `Chunk()` of 512x512 tiles. After grouping I need to split the Chunk (this is the part I want to optmise) and then debounce each subtile separately. I've got it all working, it's just slow. The whole picture isn't really relevant to optimising this one specific part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this with 3 fixes

1. I didn't need to create sub-tiles for small zoom levels.
2. Instead of calculating the chunk position for each tile, I instead calculated the position once and then verified if the remaining tiles was within this chunk a 'chunk boundary'
3. I refactored so that instead of splitting a large chunk into smaller chunks, I built up larger chunks from smaller chunks

The result is twice as fast, when using my basic example. In the full-fat code with real data it's *significantly* faster, and that's without any further improvements (e.g. using coroutines to process
in parallel).

### CSS render pixelated

Originally I created smaller tiles because the tiles became blurry as I zoomed in.

[image: zoomed in Factorio map tile - showing blurry pixels]

However, the original map data is all just pixels. Zooming in doesn't increase the amount of pixels.
If you open up the source image in a basic image editor, like Paint, and zoom in you'll see this
source image doesn't blur.

[image: Factorio map of desert terrain]

The tiles became blurry because my web browser was 'optimising' the images. Instead, I set the CSS
property [`image-rendering: pixelated`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering)
. This disables the optimisation.

Because of this I no longer need to create zoomed in tiles. Leaflet can instead dynamically scale
the larger images.

### Group by chunk boundary

Instead of the 'expensive' `toChunkPosition()` used to determine if a tile is in a specific
chunk, I instead created a 'chunk boundary' that has two boundary points - 'left top' and 'right
bottom'.

```kotlin
data class ChunkPositionBounds(
  val leftTop: TilePosition,
  val rightBottom: TilePosition,
) : ClosedRange<TilePosition> {

  constructor(chunkPosition: ChunkPosition, chunkSize: ChunkSize) : this(
    chunkPosition.leftTopTile(chunkSize),
    chunkPosition.rightBottomTile(chunkSize),
  )

  override val start: TilePosition
    get() = leftTop

  override val endInclusive: TilePosition
    get() = rightBottom
}
```

I implemented the `ClosedRange<MapTilePosition>` so I can create a nice operator function
for `MapChunkPosition`

```kotlin
data class ChunkPosition(val x: Int, val y: Int) {

   fun leftTopTile(chunkSize: ChunkSize): TilePosition =
      TilePosition(
         x * chunkSize.lengthInTiles,
         y * chunkSize.lengthInTiles,
      )

   fun rightBottomTile(chunkSize: ChunkSize): TilePosition =
      leftTopTile(chunkSize) + (chunkSize.lengthInTiles - 1)
}
```

Now given a chunk I can verify all its tiles have the correct position

```kotlin
/** Verify all [tiles][Chunk.tiles] are contained within [chunk] */
fun validateChunk(chunk: Chunk): Chunk {

   val (validTiles, invalidTiles) = chunk.tiles.entries.partition { (tilePos, _) ->
      tilePos in chunk
   }

   return if (invalidTiles.isNotEmpty()) {
      println("WARNING Chunk $chunk contained ${invalidTiles.size}/${chunk.tiles.size} out-of-bounds tiles $invalidTiles")
      chunk.copy(tiles = validTiles.associate { it.key to it.value })
   } else {
      chunk
   }
}
```

#### Re-use previously grouped tiles

The final optimisation is that I only grouped tiles into a chunk in this per-tile basis once.
Once I was sure the input data was 'clean', I could re-use the chunked data to create larger
tiles.

(This optimisation is not so important given that smaller tiles are not needed thanks to the
css-rendering trick - but I'll describe it in case someone else finds this useful.)

```kotlin
/**
 * Get all chunks of size [srcChunkSize] from [srcChunks], then for each source chunk
 * create a new [ChunkPosition], based on [newChunkSize].
 *
 * Group the chunks by the new position, and merge the tiles of each chunk.
 */
fun regroupByChunkSize(
  srcChunks: List<Chunk>,
  srcChunkSize: ChunkSize,
  newChunkSize: ChunkSize,
): List<Chunk> {

  return srcChunks
    .filter { it.size == srcChunkSize }
    .groupBy { chunk ->
      chunk.position
        .leftTopTile(chunk.size)
        .toChunkPosition(newChunkSize)
    }.map { (newChunkPosition, chunks) ->

      val tiles = chunks.flatMap {
        it.tiles.entries
      }.associate { (k, v) -> k to v }

      Chunk(
        tiles = tiles,
        size = newChunkSize,
        position = newChunkPosition,
      )
    }
}
```

I could then iteratively call `regroupByChunkSize(...)` to incrementally aggregate chunks.

```kotlin
fun aggregateChunks(
  sourceChunks: List<Chunk>
): List<Chunk> {

  val allGroupedChunks = mutableListOf<Chunk>()

  val groupedChunks032 = sourceChunks.map { chunk -> validateChunk(chunk) }

  allGroupedChunks += groupedChunks032
  allGroupedChunks += regroupByChunkSize(allGroupedChunks, ChunkSize.CHUNK_032, ChunkSize.CHUNK_064)
  allGroupedChunks += regroupByChunkSize(allGroupedChunks, ChunkSize.CHUNK_064, ChunkSize.CHUNK_128)
  allGroupedChunks += regroupByChunkSize(allGroupedChunks, ChunkSize.CHUNK_128, ChunkSize.CHUNK_256)
  allGroupedChunks += regroupByChunkSize(allGroupedChunks, ChunkSize.CHUNK_256, ChunkSize.CHUNK_512)

  return allGroupedChunks.toList()
}
```

(This could be improved. Also, this example looks strange. The actual code I'm using is using Kafka,
so `sourceChunks` is a live updating list, and each `regroupByChunkSize(...)` call is an independent
Stream Task.)

#### Full example code

This code is very scruffy. I'm just using it for demo purposes.

If you want to use smaller chunk sizes, then change

`val lengthInTiles: Int = 2f.pow(8 - zoomLevel).roundToInt()`

to

`val lengthInTiles: Int = 2f.pow(3 - zoomLevel).roundToInt()`

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.floor
import kotlin.math.pow
import kotlin.math.roundToInt
import kotlin.random.Random
import kotlin.random.nextInt
import kotlin.time.measureTimedValue


fun main() {
  val sourceChunks = testData()

  val (chunks, time) = measureTimedValue {
    aggregateChunks(sourceChunks)
  }

//  chunks.forEach {
//    println("-------")
//    printChunk(it)
//  }
//  println("-------")
  println("took: $time")
}


fun aggregateChunks(
  sourceChunks: List<Chunk>
): List<Chunk> {

  val allGroupedChunks = mutableListOf<Chunk>()

  val groupedChunks032 = sourceChunks.map { chunk -> validateChunk(chunk) }

  allGroupedChunks += groupedChunks032
  allGroupedChunks += regroupByChunkSize(allGroupedChunks, ChunkSize.CHUNK_032, ChunkSize.CHUNK_064)
  allGroupedChunks += regroupByChunkSize(allGroupedChunks, ChunkSize.CHUNK_064, ChunkSize.CHUNK_128)
  allGroupedChunks += regroupByChunkSize(allGroupedChunks, ChunkSize.CHUNK_128, ChunkSize.CHUNK_256)
  allGroupedChunks += regroupByChunkSize(allGroupedChunks, ChunkSize.CHUNK_256, ChunkSize.CHUNK_512)

  return allGroupedChunks.toList()
}


/** Verify all [tiles][Chunk.tiles] are contained within [chunk] */
fun validateChunk(chunk: Chunk): Chunk {

  val (validTiles, invalidTiles) = chunk.tiles.entries.partition { (tilePos, _) ->
    tilePos in chunk
  }

  return if (invalidTiles.isNotEmpty()) {
    println("WARNING Chunk $chunk contained ${invalidTiles.size}/${chunk.tiles.size} out-of-bounds tiles $invalidTiles")
    chunk.copy(tiles = validTiles.associate { it.key to it.value })
  } else {
    chunk
  }
}


/**
 * Get all chunks of size [srcChunkSize] from [srcChunks], then for each source chunk
 * create a new [ChunkPosition], based on [newChunkSize].
 *
 * Group the chunks by the new position, and merge the tiles of each chunk.
 */
fun regroupByChunkSize(
  srcChunks: List<Chunk>,
  srcChunkSize: ChunkSize,
  newChunkSize: ChunkSize,
): List<Chunk> {

  return srcChunks
    .filter { it.size == srcChunkSize }
    .groupBy { chunk ->
      chunk.position
        .leftTopTile(chunk.size)
        .toChunkPosition(newChunkSize)
    }.map { (newChunkPosition, chunks) ->

      val tiles = chunks.flatMap {
        it.tiles.entries
      }.associate { (k, v) -> k to v }

      Chunk(
        tiles = tiles,
        size = newChunkSize,
        position = newChunkPosition,
      )
    }
}


fun printChunk(chunk: Chunk) {
  println("chunk ${chunk.position} ${chunk.size}")
  val minX = chunk.tiles.keys.minOf { it.x }
  val minY = chunk.tiles.keys.minOf { it.y }
  val maxX = chunk.tiles.keys.maxOf { it.x }
  val maxY = chunk.tiles.keys.maxOf { it.y }

  (minY..maxY).forEach { y ->
    (minX..maxX).forEach { x ->
      print(chunk.tiles[TilePosition(x, y)]?.rgba ?: " ")
    }
    println()
  }
}


data class Chunk(
  val tiles: Map<TilePosition, Colour>,
  val size: ChunkSize,
  val position: ChunkPosition,
) {

  val bounds: ChunkPositionBounds by lazy {
    ChunkPositionBounds(position, size)
  }

  operator fun contains(tilePosition: TilePosition): Boolean {
    return tilePosition in bounds
  }
}


data class ChunkPositionBounds(
  val leftTop: TilePosition,
  val rightBottom: TilePosition,
) : ClosedRange<TilePosition> {

  constructor(chunkPosition: ChunkPosition, chunkSize: ChunkSize) : this(
    chunkPosition.leftTopTile(chunkSize),
    chunkPosition.rightBottomTile(chunkSize),
  )

  override val start: TilePosition
    get() = leftTop

  override val endInclusive: TilePosition
    get() = rightBottom
}


data class Colour(val rgba: String)

data class TilePosition(val x: Int, val y: Int) : Comparable<TilePosition> {

  override operator fun compareTo(other: TilePosition): Int =
    when {
      other.x != x -> x.compareTo(other.x)
      else         -> y.compareTo(other.y)
    }

  operator fun plus(addend: Int) =
    TilePosition(x + addend, y + addend)

  fun toChunkPosition(chunkSize: ChunkSize) =
    ChunkPosition(
      floor(x.toDouble() / chunkSize.lengthInTiles.toDouble()).toInt(),
      floor(y.toDouble() / chunkSize.lengthInTiles.toDouble()).toInt(),
    )
}


data class ChunkPosition(val x: Int, val y: Int) {

  fun leftTopTile(chunkSize: ChunkSize): TilePosition =
    TilePosition(
      x * chunkSize.lengthInTiles,
      y * chunkSize.lengthInTiles,
    )

  fun rightBottomTile(chunkSize: ChunkSize): TilePosition =
    leftTopTile(chunkSize) + (chunkSize.lengthInTiles - 1)
}


enum class ChunkSize(
  val zoomLevel: Int,
) : Comparable<ChunkSize> {
  CHUNK_512(-1),
  CHUNK_256(0),
  CHUNK_128(1),
  CHUNK_064(2),
  CHUNK_032(3),
  ;

  /** 1, 2, 4, 8, or 16 */
  val lengthInTiles: Int = 2f.pow(8 - zoomLevel).roundToInt()

  companion object {
    val entries: Set<ChunkSize> = values().toSet()

    val MAX: ChunkSize = entries.maxByOrNull { it.lengthInTiles }!!
    val MIN: ChunkSize = entries.minByOrNull { it.lengthInTiles }!!
  }
}

fun testData(): List<Chunk> {
  val r = Random(1)

  val src = List(x.ChunkSize.MAX.lengthInTiles) {
    List(x.ChunkSize.MAX.lengthInTiles) { r.nextInt(0..9).toString() }
  }

  return src.flatMapIndexed { y, row ->
    row.mapIndexed { x, colour ->
      val tilePos = TilePosition(x, y)
      val tileColour = Colour("$colour")
      Chunk(
        tiles = mapOf(tilePos to tileColour),
        size = ChunkSize.MIN,
        position = tilePos.toChunkPosition(ChunkSize.MIN),
      )
    }
  }
}
```